# knowing that some entry located in the database

Tags: c#, database, algorithm

I have some table in my database and i want to know if some entry really located there before i really go there .

I have some fast application and i want to lower the number of calls against the database .

I have there about 35.000 entries in the table.

I thought to have a bloom filter with some kind of hash function .

Is it a good idea or you have other ideas what to do here ?

Thanks .

Comment: 35k entries is not really a lot, a well designed table should be able to look that data up in no time.

Comment: leppie: The problem here Is slow network.

Comment: leppie: I am talking about 14 database calls in a second in the worst time. and i afraid of slow network.

Answer (score 2):

If you are worried about your database calls being too slow perhaps you just put an index on your database. This will improve the speed of lookups and you may find that you don't need your local cache.

If you really want a local cache, you can use a `HashSet<T>` to store the keys of your records. Use `hashSet.Contains` to see if a key is present in approximately O(1) time.

Since you're already implementing a cache of your database, you may also want to consider storing the data from the table locally too, not just the keys. For this you can use a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`.

Comment: @Night Walker: HashSet is not available in .NET 2.0, but Dictionary is. In .NET 2.0 you can use a Dictionary instead of a HashSet - just store null as the value. Or find an external library that provides an implementation of HashSet.

Comment: @Mark Byers:when the databse changes how I can get the new Dictionary with the new tables. Without going to the database and building a new one .

Comment: @Mark Byers: we are talking about hash table in size 125 mega, 35000 * 32 bits . I see my idea not good .

Comment: @Night Walker: I don't understand how 35000 * 32bits = 125 mega(bytes?).

Answer (score 0):

What about just cache the whole datatable in your local memory.

And select  rows from the local memory